# Rails Download error in Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin

While installing rails in cygwin . I am getting this error

```
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-atomic_reference-dir
        --without-atomic_reference-dir
        --with-atomic_reference-include
        --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
        --with-atomic_reference-lib
        --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/lib
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:712:in `try_run'
        from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I tried different solution .Most of the tutorial on net talk about installing development package. But cygwin package manager gives many package when develop is search . Can anybody tell what i am missing here or can point to detailed tutorial on installing ROR using cygwin in Windows 7.

Comment: Not an answer, I know - sorry, but you'll have a lot better luck with http://rubyinstaller.org/ (including the devkit). Doing it with cygwin creates this type of error for a ton of gems, and just isn't worth the effort, imho.

Comment: what is the best OS for ROR development. I am thinking to move to ubuntu.

Comment: I recently moved to Ubuntu from Windows, just for ROR development, and it's been awesome. It even works pretty well in VirtualBox, if you want to try it out without a large commitment. I've had pretty good luck using Rubymine, and its integrated version control made me not even miss tortoise git as much as I thought I would... Good luck!

Comment: FWIW, the tests run noticeably faster in Ubuntu on the same hardware, for me, in addition to the increased ease of installation.

Comment: FYI, Rails is available from Cygwin Ports in the `ruby-rails` package.